# Using CollapsingToolbar animation only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

**The brief question:** What is the best way of having a collapsing view (like `CollapsingToolbarLayout`) which is not your toolbar?

**And the long story:**
I have an application which lists user application and let him to lock em.
So I created an `Activity` with a solid (and fixed) `Toolbar` and a `RecyclerView` inside it. The fixed toolbar is common between all of the activities inside my application (so I cannot change the way it is).
Also there are some kind of warnings which have to be shown to the user. I decided to show these warnings as a **Collapsing** view above the list. (which collapses as user scrolls down on the list)
So far, I used a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` below the fixed toolbar. Here is the most important parts of my code.

```
<include layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <LinearLayout
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                <!-- My custom warnings view here -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The output is the image below (which looks like what I want): 
[image] 

But there is several issues in scrolling animation. Sometimes it returns up when I scroll it down (looks like it is bouncing!), and sometimes `RecyclerView` scrolls independent of the toolbar (and some items go behind it)

I think the problem is that I should not use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` this way.

So

> What is the best way of having a collapsing view (like `CollapsingToolbarLayout`) which is not truly your toolbar.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Put your toolbar in CollpasingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

Place your RecyclerView just between`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>` and `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is there right now and I didn't mentioned it because it's not the problem. The problem is above the `RecyclerView`, it is how `LinearLayout` behaves.